# CSS background-color does not match in stylesheet and in browser

Tags: html, css, background-color

I faced with a wierd behavior of the input[type="submit"] background color. Colors doesn't match: in my css-file color few sahdes darker than in the browser.

Rule from the stylesheet:

```
input[type=submit] {background-color: #000;}
```

But on the screenshot this element has background-color - #313131. Problem appears in Chrome and Firefox. 
Do you have any suggestion, what could it be? Thanks

**UPD:**
Problem solved. It was a typo that changed opacity of the wrapper. Sorry, guys and thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Maybe show us a fiddle which reproduces the issue.

Comment: In your developer tools, you can see where the style is coming from.

Comment: Do other styles overwrite this css rule? Please attach the screenshot and a jsfiddle would be nice.

Comment: In the developer tools, in "computed" tab there are the right bg-color - rgb(0,0,0). Button doesn't has any overlays or opacity.

Ok, I will make efforts and in case of unsuccess I'll replicate it on a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Place this code in internal style tag or place this at last of external stylesheet. to get priority 
`input[type='submit']{background:#000 !important;}/`

Answer (score -1):

Set a "class" attribute for Your button and then give it "background-color" property in .css file.It's better than styling all input submit buttons You are going to use in the future.

Comment: If the current `background-color` CSS  rule on the element comes from a selector that has an id in it your solution will not work.

Comment: If think that You didn't understand me.Read my answer again and again, after that read it one more time.First of all I didn't mentioned something about `id` like You did.I mean something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/tuzxjrn5/).Your downvote makes no sense, sorry.